# Работа с GET/POST и брузером

Tags: java, http, javafx, url, twitch

Нужно реализовать такой функционал для входа в приложение через twitch. Пользователь в приложении (написанном на JavaFx) нажимает кнопку Login, открывается окно браузера со ссылкой на вход. (средствами twitch api). 
После того, как пользователь нажимает "Разрешить" twtich отправляет запрос с Токеном на вход в приложение.

[image: Страница входа в приложение через twitch]

### Хочу реализовать следующий функционал:

- 1)Пользователь после нажатия на кнопку переходит на страницу с
  подтверждением входа
- 2)Пользователь нажимает кнопку разрешить
- 3)Twitch присылает token. Нужно его каким-то образом получить с
  помощью java
- 4)Присвоить переменной полученный токен.

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может быть для решения вашей задачи подойдет seneium web driver. Первые два пункта точно. Насчет третьего не уверен.